# Recommend html element theme engine for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

Is it any theme or css framework can apply to ASP.NET?
I work with ASP.NET webform, everybody known web controls generate pure html to work.

But i am not good at graphic design, so I want to find some UI helper.
I already work with jQuery and Ajax Controll Tookit, but it not much help to make a modern UI design.

I have found some commercial library like ComponentArt,DevExpress etc, but is it any free or opensource I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Controls generate pure html.  The only "odd" item that is added is the id of the control.  In ASP.Net 4.0 you can determine how the ID is generated - including eliminating the id generated by the .Net Framework.  You can set this in the web.config with the value

```
<pages clientIDMode="Static">
```

Read more about ClientIDMode [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx).

Now, you can add a CssClass to a control and use that to style, which is the best way to go.

You can search google for "ASP.Net Web Page Templates" or "ASP.Net Web Design Templates", but you are still going to have to handle some CSS yourself.